# Search large array for lowest number

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Hey everyone so I have a very large array that has names and popularity ranks listed in them, and generally the lower the number the more popular that name is. I need a way to search through the array to find 20 of the lowest numbers for a certain decade. So let me show you what my list looks like and my code.

[This is my list.](http://www.writeurl.com/text/ew40igzvms0lvavaf6h1/7mwg41itnrkgyqy37gy8/lbda0mglln5bjue1pdzr)

And here is my code:

Name

```
public class Name{

private String givenName;
private int[] ranks = new int[11];

public Name(String name, int[] popularityRanks){
    givenName = name;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        ranks[i] = popularityRanks[i];
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return givenName;
}

public int getPop(int decade){
    if (decade >= 1 && decade <= 11){
        return ranks[decade];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

public String getHistoLine(int decade){
    String histoLine = ranks[decade] + ": ";

    return histoLine;
}

public String getHistogram(){
    String histogram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        histogram += ranks[i] + ": " + this.getHistoLine(i)
                + "\n";
    }

    return histogram;
}
}
```

And then NameApp:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp{

private static boolean validInput;
private static boolean stillWorking = true;
private static boolean validDecade;

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] nameArray = readNamesFile();
    Name[] list = new Name[nameArray.length];

    loadNames(list, nameArray);

    char choice;

    do {

        do {

            displayMenu();
            choice = getUserInput();

        } while (!validInput);

        switch (choice){
            case 'A':
                    displayHistogram(list);
                break;
            case 'B':
                    compareTwoNames(list);
                break;
            case 'C':
                    displayTopTenNames(list);
                break;
            case 'D':
                    writeAnomaliesToFile(list);
                    stillWorking = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    } while (stillWorking);
}   

private static String[] readNamesFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] nameArray = new String[4429];

    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String fileName = "names.txt";
    inputStream = new Scanner (new File(fileName));

    int i = 0;

    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        nameArray[i] = inputStream.nextLine();

        i++;
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return nameArray;
}

private static void loadNames(Name[] list, String[] nameArray){
    int length;
    int spacePos;
    int[] popRanks = new int[11];
    String name;
    String linePop;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
        length = nameArray[i].length();

        spacePos = nameArray[i].indexOf(" ");

        name = nameArray[i].substring(0,spacePos);
        linePop = nameArray[i].substring(spacePos + 1, length);

        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
            popRanks[j] = Integer.parseInt(linePop.split(" ")[j]);
        }

        list[i] = new Name(name, popRanks);
    }
}

private static void displayMenu(){
    System.out.println("Enter the character corresponding to your selection:");
    System.out.println("\ta - Print histogram for a name");
    System.out.println("\tb - Compare two names in a decade");
    System.out.println("\tc - Print top ten names for a decade");
    System.out.println("\td - Quit (display file anomalies)");
}

private static char getUserInput(){

    String selection = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("   Your selection: " + selection);

    checkUserInput(selection);

    char choice = stringToChar(selection);

    return choice;
}

private static boolean checkUserInput(String selection){

    if (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("c") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again...");
        return validInput = false;
    }
    else {          
        return validInput = true;
    }

}

private static char stringToChar(String selection){
    char choice = selection.charAt(0);

    choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

    return choice;
}

private static void displayHistogram(Name[] list){
    String nameInput;
    String histogram;
    int nameLocation;

    nameInput = nameEntry();

    nameLocation = checkListArray(nameInput, list);

    histogram = list[nameLocation].getHistogram();

    System.out.println("Histogram for name, " + list[nameLocation].getName() + ":");
    System.out.println(histogram);
}

private static void compareTwoNames(Name[] list){
    String nameOne;
    String nameTwo;
    String oneHistoLine;
    String twoHistoLine;
    int oneLocation;
    int twoLocation;
    int decade;

    nameOne = nameEntry();
    oneLocation = checkListArray(nameOne, list);

    nameTwo = nameEntry();
    twoLocation = checkListArray(nameTwo, list);

    decadeMenu();
    decade = decadeSelection();

    oneHistoLine = list[oneLocation].getHistoLine(decade);
    twoHistoLine = list[twoLocation].getHistoLine(decade);

    System.out.println("Data for " + list[oneLocation].getName());
    System.out.println(" " + oneHistoLine);
    System.out.println("Data for " + list[twoLocation].getName());
    System.out.println(" " + twoHistoLine);
}

private static void displayTopTenNames(Name[] list){
    int decade;
    int temp = 1000;
    int tempTwo;
    String[] topTen = new String[20];

    decadeMenu();
    decade = decadeSelection();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
            if (list[j].getPop(decade) > 0 && list[j].getPop(decade) < temp){
                temp = list[j].getPop(decade);
                tempTwo = 
            }
        }
    }

}

private static void writeAnomaliesToFile(Name[] list){

}

private static String nameEntry(){
    String nameInput = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");

    nameInput = keyboard.nextLine();

    return nameInput;

}

private static int checkListArray(String nameInput, Name[] list){
    int nameLocation = -1;
    int listLength = list.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
        if (nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase(list[i].getName())){
            return nameLocation = i;
        }
    }

    if (nameLocation == -1){
        System.out.println("The name, " + nameInput + ", was not found!");
        return nameLocation;
    }
    return nameLocation;
}

private static void decadeMenu(){
    System.out.println("Enter number correpsonding to your decade:");
    System.out.println("   1 - 1900-1909");
    System.out.println("   2 - 1910-1919");
    System.out.println("   3 - 1920-1929");
    System.out.println("   4 - 1930-1939");
    System.out.println("   5 - 1940-1949");
    System.out.println("   6 - 1950-1959");
    System.out.println("   7 - 1960-1969");
    System.out.println("   8 - 1970-1979");
    System.out.println("   9 - 1980-1989");
    System.out.println("   10 - 1990-1999");
    System.out.println("   11 - 2000-2005");
}

private static int decadeSelection(){
    String decadeChoice;
    int decade;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
        decadeChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

        decade = checkDecade(decadeChoice);

    } while (!validDecade);

    return decade;
}

private static int checkDecade(String decadeChoice){
    int decade = 0;

    try {
        decade = Integer.parseInt(decadeChoice);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("That is not an integer. Please try again.");

        return decade;
    }

    if (decade < 1 || decade > 11){
        System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 11");

        validDecade = false;
        return decade;
    }
    else {
        validDecade = true;

        return decade;
    }
}
}
```

so where I need help at is the displayTopTenNames method. I was sort of messing around with it a bit earlier but every loop that I have come up with always makes duplicates that I don't want... Anyway my output should look like this:

Ten most popular names (male and female) during the decade 1910-1919 were:

John (1)            Mary (1)
    Helen (2)           William (2)
    Dorothy (3)         James (3)
    Margaret (4)        Robert (4)
    Joseph (5)          Ruth (5)
    George (6)          Mildred (6)
    Anna (7)            Charles (7)
    Edward (8)          Elizabeth (8)
    Frances (9)         Frank (9)
    Marie (10)          Walter (10)

so yeah help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but this shows the theory. You maintain a small list of 20 items. You scan your large list to see if its a candidate for your short list. If the list is small than 20, anything gets added. If it has reached 20, you check to see if anything in the list is larger than the item you would like to add. if it is, this item is evicted and replaced with the smaller value.

```
public class Low20 {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new Low20();
    }

    public Low20() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int x=0;x<100000;x++) {
            add(random.nextInt(100000));
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        if (list.size() < 20) {
            list.add(value);
        } else {
            for (int x=0;x<list.size();x++) {
                if (list.get(x) > value) {
                    list.remove(x);
                    list.add(value);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result. (random numbers, but the lowest 20). You could then sort these, or incorporate sort into the eviction algorithm.

[6, 0, 5, 17, 18, 11, 10, 27, 22, 27, 28, 16, 34, 33, 0, 8, 28, 0, 15, 14]

The benefit of this method over using a blanket sort on your list, is that your list doesn't have to fit in memory and can be applied from a file or database scan.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Arrays.sort() method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html